# Raid Controller not recognizing hdds after removal. Poweredge 6950

Tags: hard-drive, dell, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, raid0

I have a Dell Poweredge 6950 running server 2012 with 4 hdds. 80gb raptor (with OS), 2 500gb WD black in raid 0 and a 1tb raptor.

I shut off the server, removed the 2 hdds in raid and the 1tb raptor. Then I turned it on, realized I forgot a file on the raid, turned it off, put the hdds back in (in the same spot too) and now it wont recognize the raid or the 1tb raptor.

I took the raptor back out and it works fine in my other computer, and obliviously the raid ones wouldn't.

I bought the server with them in raid 0 and I was going to take them out this weekend but then this happened...

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your raid controller to see what the status is of the hard drives.  If your green on all you should then go into disk management and check to see if the disks show.  If they are there but show as foreign or inactive you'll need to either import them back or set them to active.

Comment: +1: Trying to import the foreign config is the right answer. For a Dell in the X950 series, the raid data is stored on the disks, so they should be available to import.